# FC20 - Remote Desktop to QEMU Host

Tags: fedora, qemu, remote-desktop

I've got a Fedora 20 Workstation that I'm trying to enable desktop sharing on.
The additional complication is that this Workstation is also running QEMU for local virtual machines.

I've followed the steps [here](http://ask.xmodulo.com/enable-configure-desktop-sharing-linux-mint-cinnamon-desktop.html) to enable desktop sharing, however I'm struggling to connect.

Looking at netstat, I can see that *qemu-system* appears to be listening on the standard VNC port:

> sudo netstat -apn |grep 590
> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5900          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7221/qemu-system-x8
> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5901          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31103/qemu-system-x
> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5902          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5522/qemu-system-x8
> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5903          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20180/qemu-system-x

I've tried setting *org.gnome.Vino alternative-port* to 5999, however now nothing is listening.

> $ gsettings get org.gnome.Vino alternative-port
> uint16 5999
> $ sudo netstat -apn |grep 5999
>
> $

How can I enable desktop sharing on a QEMU host successfully?